# Is there any special order of finding variables in Python?

Tags: python, variables, scope, namespaces

I am quite confused with LEGB rule.

At line 7, I was expecting 4 to be printed but it keeps printing 5.
I am aware of the fact that whenever the bar() method is called, it looks for variable x in foo()'s scope since it doesn't have x declared in the local scope(bar()'s scope). but when the bar() method is called for the second time, It prints 5 rather than 4.

Why are the results from first bar() and second bar() different in terms of LEGB rule?

Here is the following code:

```
def foo():
    x=4
    def bar():
        print(x)  # Accesses x from foo's scope
    bar()  # Prints 4
    x=5
    bar()  # Prints 5 <---- Line 7

foo()
```

Comment: I don't understand why that confuses you. In the enclosing scope, x is now 5.

Comment: `bar` does not remember the value of `x`, the name is looked up every time you call `bar`. If you set `x` to `5`, `bar` will print `5`.

Comment: Oh, sorry if I was asking vaguely. I understood LEGB as finding unknown variables from top to bottom in enclosing scope. So, whenever the bar() is called, shouldn't it be searching the x over again from the top in foo()'s scope even though it is being called for the second time? and to stop when it detects x = 4? That was the reason why I think it should print 4.

Comment: If your mental model were correct, reassignment of variables would be impossible in Python. `x = 'hello'; x = 'world'; print(x)` would print `'hello'`. I hope you agree that would be a mess. Checking the local scope is different to reading the literal code from top to bottom. Add `print(locals())` lines before calling `bar`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @timgeb! but I think I am confused because it is related to functions. I thought whenever the bar() code is called, it runs the original code from line 3 to 4 and finds x from line 2.

Comment: @poream3387: It finds that _variable_ more or less as you say, but the _value_ it finds is the one most recently put there.

Comment: `bar` always runs the code in line 4. Finding the value of `x` is not done by parsing the source code before `bar` every time :)

Comment: Thank you for your effort and answers guys! I think I should study LEGB again : ) Maybe I have the wrong concepts of it.